# Change name/label of a Basic Block (in llvm pass)

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

Is there a way to change the name/label of a particular basic block in llvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BasicBlock` is a `Value`, and thus it has a `setName` method.